# Jung cannot paint white Rectangle as vertex

Tags: java, swing, colors, paint, jung

I'm trying to fill a Rectangle shaped vertex in Jung, as mentioned in exmaples and docs, I used a `Transformer`:

```
        Transformer<String, Paint> vertexColor = new Transformer<String,Paint>() {
        public Paint transform(String i) {
                return Color.WHITE;
        }
    };
```

and right after the instruction:

```
        vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexColor);
```

where vv is `VisualizationViewer`.
But the `Transformer`is not working, it continues to say `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Color to Paint` though many tutorials show the same lines.

The complete method is:

```
    @PluginVariant(requiredParameterLabels = {0})
public static JComponent visualize(final UIPluginContext context, final OWLOntologia ontology) {

    JPanel base = new JPanel();

    Graph<String, String> grafo = OntologyGraph.getGraph(ontology);

    Layout<String, String> layout = new TreeLayout<String, String>((Forest<String, String>) grafo);
    layout.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    VisualizationViewer<String, String> vv = new VisualizationViewer<String, String>(layout);
    vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300000, 300000));

    Transformer<String, Shape> vertexShape = new Transformer<String, Shape>(){
        @Override
        public Rectangle transform(String arg0) {
            Rectangle nodo = new Rectangle();
            nodo.height = 80;
            nodo.width = 200;

            return nodo;
        }
    };


    Transformer<String, Paint> vertexColor = new Transformer<String,Paint>() {
        public Paint transform(String i) {
                return Color.WHITE;
        }
    };


    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexColor);
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexShapeTransformer(vertexShape);
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<String>());
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<String>());
    vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);

    final DefaultModalGraphMouse<String, Number> graphMouse3 = new DefaultModalGraphMouse<>();
    vv.setGraphMouse(graphMouse3);
    graphMouse3.setMode(DefaultModalGraphMouse.Mode.PICKING);

    base.add(vv);

    return base;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do your imports say? My guess is that either your Color or Paint got imported from javafx (or somewhere else other than java.awt).